# How to use the UTC time zone with the Angular date filter?

Tags: angularjs, filter, timezone, utc

so I have this time in one of my objects: 2014-09-20T22:00:08.856Z

I want to display this like Day Month Year, h:mm:ss pm/am in my app.

I've tried following the angular docs and did this:

```
 {{mytime |  date : 'MMMM d y, h:mm:ss a' : UTC}}
```

here's a plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/UQV31HY7xebo17j7zAWY?p=info

I'd like to display it in UTC timezone but it's displaying pacific time... grrr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would pass `'UTC'` (in quotes).  However, you're referencing Angular 1.2, and the time zone parameter isn't available.  It was added for Angular 1.3.

You could try the latest release candidate of Angular 1.3, or you might instead consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with the [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) filter.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I'll go with moment.js for now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Looking at the docs for angular-moment, I'm not sure they've exposed a filter for moment's `utc()` function.  But you can always call it on the model directly, or write your own filter that calls it.